# Streaming audio from an Android device to another

Tags: android, sockets, audio, streaming, android-mediaplayer

How would I go about streaming audio from one device to another over the internet? I'm aware of sending basic data using Java sockets, but wondering how to:

1. Start streaming midway through a file (say, during the middle of a song)
2. What format is needed for the data being sent. MediaPlayer can take a url as a data source, so how should the audio be represented when being sent from the server side?

Thanks

Comment: If you need p2p streaming I really advice you to consider WebRTC.

Answer (score 1):

Having implemented a music streaming app, I can share a little with you.

If you want to stream and use the Android MediaPlayer class, MP3 or OGG is your best bet for a format.

If your architecture is client-server, i.e. real server in the Internet serving streams to Android devices, then just stream MP3 or OGG bytes over HTTP. Just point MediaPlayer to a URL on on your server.

If your architecture is peer-to-peer with your own custom socket code, you can create a "proxy http" server that listens on localhost on a dedicated thread. You point your MediaPlayer instance to your local in-process socket server (e.g. http://localhost:54321/MyStream.mp3).  Then you have to implement code to parse the HTTP get request form MediaPlayer, then proxy the stream bytes between your custom P2P socket protocol and listeners connected to your local http server.  A lot of radio streaming apps do exactly this so as to parse the ICECAST metadata from the MP3 stream. [Here's the code I use for my radio streaming app](https://github.com/jselbie/wrekonline/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/selbie/wrek/metaproxy) that does this.

For the "start midway through the file" scenario, you might find my [MP3 Stream Reader class](https://github.com/jselbie/mp3streamreader/blob/master/MP3StreamReader.java) useful.  It wraps an InputStream (file, socket stream, etc..) and syncs to the next valid frame from where ever you started from.  Just call `read_next_chunk` to get the next block of audio and its format.  MediaPlayer might do most of this heavy lifting for you, so this might not be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I'm understanding you correctly, the process is to run a socket thread at the local address, which accepts the GET request from the MediaPlayer, take the client address from that and forwards the stream data from file to that address? The only thing I'm confused about is the proxy server; how is that built to send the data internally?

Comment: On the listening side, MediaPlayer connects to `http://localhost:12345`. You have a dedicated server thread that listens for connections on port 12345. When the mediaplayer thread connects to your in-process server, you stream audio to it.  You "get" the audio from the other side with your own socket protocol.