# Which is good WebRtc or wifi P2P to share audio from one device to another device

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, android-mediaplayer, wifip2p

I have music player and need to add sync play functionality with other mobile. For example if 2 or more users are using my music player and want to play same song on all devices then they just connect through same network and can play music on all devices from one device with complete music player control of all devices on single device.

Would anyone explain me which is best and how can I share audio from one Android device to another device on Sync and what are the steps to do so.

Points I know about WiFi P2P-

- create connection
- create socket for sharing
- share a complete file

Points I want to know:-

- How can I share file without storing in another device storage.
- How to play sound on both devices at same position (ON SYNC).

and after Wifi P2P I want to say that I don't know about WebRTC like:-

- How it works?
- How to setup connection for this ?
- Is it always required internet connection ?
- Is same application is required in both devices to create connection between devices?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354159/295004 You should list what you've tried and what isn't working, else this seems like a request for a tutorial which is off-topic.

Comment: buddy i don't want tutorial but actually i don't know how can i do this but i know it is required wifi p2p connection but afterward i don't know how to go to achieve it

Comment: Audio streaming is a specialized area of knowledge. Saying you '"don't know how to go to achieve it" isn't a useful statement. A better question would be picking a path or a particular part of the your problem, showing what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: can you please tell me which things required i need to implement after p2p connection

Comment: Have you read the link I provided? The author of the answer has an open source app as reference, with what appears to be appropriate keywords for further research.

Comment: hey @MorrisonChang i am getting some research and found that webRTC can do something like that so if you are able to provide me answer for that so it will very grateful for me. and still i am searching for that may be i found my answer but i am also waiting for your response...

Comment: You've changed your question from P2P to WebRTC. Please don't do that, start a new question. They are two different things as WebRTC uses cloud server. Also this is not a research service. Good luck.

Comment: hmm actually i want suggestion that which is good and easy for user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know is this helpful for you or not just see the links may be you get some useful info...

for web rtc

```
https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/
```

This link will help you to know about webrtc like how it works and how to setup

Comment: this link is not so helpful for me but yes it is giving me some info about web rtc i am giving this upvote because today it is gonna be expire and i don't want to waste these 50 reputation